# Accessing class properties and methods from template

Tags: php, oop, opencart, opencart2.x

Prior to Opencart 2.0 class properties could be accessed directly from the template.  For example, `$this->config->get('config_language')` or `$this->request->get['route']` were both accessible from an admin template file.

With the new method `$this->load->view()`, neither of these work.  Is there a simple way to pass on class methods and properties which are available in the current controller to the tpl without explicitly adding them to the `$data` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Opencart version 2, if you want these variables then you can easily access them. There is slight change is code, now you can use

```
$this->registry
```

which holds everything. So you have to get these things form

`$this->registry`

like this

`$this->registry->get('config')`

it will work like

```
$this->config
```

so your

```
$this->config->get('config_language')
```

becomes

```
$this->registry->get('config')->get('config_language')
```

like this

```
$this->request->get['route'] == $this->registry->get('request')->get['route'];

$this->request->post['route'] == $this->registry->get('request')->post['route'];

$this->request->files['file'] == $this->registry->get('request')->files['file'];
```

for more just simply print `$this->registry` in any template.

Comment: @billynoah 1st comment - i added same code in my header.tpl (admin) - image (https://box.everhelper.me/attachment/308102/g2ErtWJkREC4gDBkwCNhzMwbA2N3T4EX/424043-vhADkCk6smHJXT2I/screen.png) and this is what i get in my view (https://box.everhelper.me/attachment/308104/g2ErtWJkREC4gDBkwCNhzMwbA2N3T4EX/424043-ZuUefADM1VtUT7R4/screen.png)

Comment: @billynoah it will be better if you post your issue after using this code, instead of just adding it's not working and about second comment you had know you are asking about template (tpl) files not controller so why i will write any thing about what's going on in your controller, it's all about template, why you assuming yourself.

Comment: sorry you are completely correct.  I made a small edit on your answer so I would be able to reverse my vote.