# Passing $this to template in Opencart - works for class properties but not parent class methods

Tags: php, oop, opencart, opencart2.3

In Opencart previously you could access controller class methods from within a template (.tpl) by simply calling `$this`:

```
$store_name = $this->config->get('config_language');
```

In Opencart 2+ this is no longer possible and it became necessary to call them via `registry` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929036/accessing-class-properties-and-methods-from-template)

```
$store_name = $this->registry->get('config')->get('config_language');
```

Now in Opencart 2.3 this doesn't work either.  So I tried simply passing `$this` to the `$data` array and this only partially works:

(in controller)

```
public $name = 'test';
...
$data['this'] = $this;
```

(in template)

```
//  The following works fine and outputs the class property $name
$this->name;

// This does not work and returns errors
// Notice: Undefined property: Template\PHP::$registry
// PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object
$this->registry->get('config')->get('config_language');
```

**QUESTION:** Why are the immediate controller class properties available, but parent class method `registry` is not?

Comment: What does $registry->get() do?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey - If you want to learn about Opencart class methods there are more appropriate venues for that.  It's not relevant to my question.

Comment: I read the source (I have it installed) and that's what Opencart was calling.  It's a diagnostic question, but I understand your comment nonetheless.  It's clear from looking @source that $registry is a global object.  Perhaps they didn't make it available in child classes because it was easy to get to otherwise?  That's where we start to get in over my head on this at present.